# Can I use GLES2/gl2.h to compile a static lib for iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

I would like to compile a static C++ lib using the standard GLES2/gl2.h headers, that I would like to link to executables for iOS and Android.
Is the header compatible with the OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h on iOS ?

Or should I compile the source of my library with iOS header in order to make sure the signatures match ?

Comment: Sounds like it should be fine, right? Maybe reality differs though. It would be absurd if the constants changed values or the functions changed signatures. All the necessarily platform dependent stuff should be corraled in EAGL, right?

Comment: That is my general feeling as well, but I wonder if someone has more concrete info regarding this.

Comment: Are you motivated by wanting to use a consistent `#include` directive on all platforms? (I came here looking for common wisdom on that issue)

Comment: Yes, for the purpose to compile static library, that i can reuse without recompiling.

Comment: Did you make any progress here?

Comment: In the end, i used my own header to include and used ifdef to switch between apple's and android's version.